# Recommend a Serial to USB cable/converter that works with modern OSes

Tags: usb, serial, communication, interface, cables

I'm hacking on a board that has an RS232 interface (via a Max232 chip).  My new computer doesn't have a serial port, which leaves me using USB.  I actually have a Serial to USB cord already, but it doesn't appear to work on any modern OS that I run (Windows 7, Linux).  I'm not 100% positive, but I think it's this one:

[http://www.amazon.com/Cables-Go-26886-Serial-Adapter/dp/B000067RVJ/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000067RVJ)

I still have the driver CD too, which worked fine in XP, but Win7 wants nothing to do with it.

So, can anyone recommend a serial to USB cord/converter that they know works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 chipsets for serial:

- [Prolific](http://www.prolific.com.tw/eng/downloads.asp?ID=31)
- [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/FTDrivers.htm)

Both are supported in modern operating systems. Just go tho the websites and download the latest drivers. The one imaged looks like mine(not to say it is) and mine is prolific.

Comment: I would upvote you 1000 times for FTDI if I could.

Comment: I have never had any issues with FTDI drivers on any OS, I would suggest it very much.

Comment: I'm going to give you an update not for FTDI (Which everyone knows) but for Prolific, which is new to me.

Comment: @Kellenjb: I've had considerable problems with FTDI if a device is plugged in while a connection is open; in my application, that's unavoidable (the software needs to be ready to receive data from a device at any time, so the connection has to stay open; it would be unacceptable to require users of the system to indicate in advance when they were going to unplug a device).

Comment: You forgot SiLabs and Microchip. (I haven't seen a USB->RS232 cable with a Microchip part yet, but given the excellent pricing, it's just a matter of time.) http://www.silabs.com/products/interface/usbtouart http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en546923

Answer (score 2):

I know for a fact that [SIIG USB to serial adapters](http://amzn.to/i6EQvE) work in Windows 7, if you get the v2 hardware.

They work on 32 and 64 bit Windows.

You also can't go wrong with those that are based on the FTDI chipset.  Many aren't, and have caused me troubles in the past by BSODing the OS quite often.   SIIG is not FTDI based, but I have yet to have one BSOD in over 5 years of running multiple of them on several systems.